# Get sum of foreign key attribute using django

Tags: django, django-queryset

```
class sales_line(models.Model):
    sales_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    item = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    qty =   models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.sales_id


class Loss(models.Models):
    sale_id = models.ForeignKey(sales_line)
```

how can i know how much quantity is lost
if the sales_id is in loss table , then the sale is lost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `Sum` from [aggregates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregations-and-other-queryset-clauses):

```
from django.db.models import Sum
lost_sales_id = Loss.objects.all().values_list('sale_id__sales_id', flat=True)
total = sales_line.objects.filter(sales_id__in=lost_sales_id).annotate(Sum('qty'))
```

You really need to optimize your models:

```
class SalesLine(models.Model):
    sales_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    item = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    qty = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.sales_id)

class Loss(models.Model):
    sale = models.ForeignKey(SalesLine)
```

Now you can do this:

```
lost_sales_id = Loss.objects.all().values_list('sale__pk', flat=True)
SalesLine.objects.filter(pk__in=lost_sales_id).annotate(Sum('qty'))
```

Comment: Why not pass the `Loss.objects.all()` queryset straight in the filter?

Comment: Because that will return a list of `Loss` objects.

Comment: what can't i use `aggregate` here instead of `annotate`. it will return sum of `qty`.

Comment: I got my answer with `aggregate`